# Force iframe link to open in same iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm using iframe to open a website in html.
However, many target attributes are _blank and _top in the website.

Therefore, the pages always open in a new window.

How to force the link open in same inframe in html?

My code below:

```
<iframe name="inapp" frameborder="0" src="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_self"></iframe>
```

Comment: You explained well but not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't if you are embedding a page from another website. There's strict cross-domain security measures in browser to prevent your page from accessing the contents of the iFrame.
If you have control over the underlying page, then that's different, but I guess you wouldn't have the target issue in the first place.

Comment: iFrame couldn't force all links open inside same iFrame? Have any other method to do?

Comment: No. It's not your website. You can't control where the links go.